# Is it possible to Dynamically destroy every child from wx.Panel in wxPython?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm making a wxPython App and I can't move anywhere until it is fixed. I am generating GUI every time I select an item from ListBox, and before I can generate it, I need to remove every single child of wx.Panel dynamically.

I've tried this ( * right =wx.Panel()  )

```
children = self.right.GetChildren()

for child in children:
    self.child.Destroy()
```

but this throws error:

> AttributeError: 'editorFrame' object has no attribute 'child'

Yeah, I don't have `child` in my `editorFrame` but I thought I can destroy every child like this.

Currently I'm destroying them like this:

```
self.classname.Destroy()
self.idname.Destroy()
self.a.Destroy()
self.position.Destroy()
self.backgroundhtml.Destroy()
self.backgroundcolorhtml.Destroy()
self.height.Destroy()
self.width.Destroy()
self.margin.Destroy()
```

but some are not created and it throws me an error too and also mentioning them all is not practical.

Comment: Try dropping the `self.` in `self.child.Destroy()`. Failing that post the code that creates self.right, assuming that is what you wish to destroy, and a few of the widgets that go into it. You appear to be on the right track.

Comment: Yes, This is working. Thank you very much.